# Deploy an app developed in VS code remote containers

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, deployment, remote-containers

I just started using vscode remote containers extension. It's quite nice as I can simply install packages in the container, I don't have to use virtual environments and I don't have to clean up packages locally. It helps me keep my local environment clean and tidy.

I was wondering, is there any way to deploy a container where I developed an app using the extension directly? I.e. remove all the stuff used only for development from the container? I saw that the dockerfile generated by the extension has some node dependencies.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.